# Set of prime ideals contain a minimal element

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, proof-verification, ideals

> I want to prove that every nonempty set of prime ideals contain a minimal element.

My attempt is to prove it by using Zorn's lemma and i would like to know if my proof is valid.

Let $\Sigma$ be a nonempty set of prime ideals. It's a partially ordered set with the partial order $a \leq b$ which means $b \subseteq a$ (note the inclusion). I will now prove that any totally ordered subset $S$ of $\Sigma$ has an upper bound.

So let $S$ be such subset and consider $J^{\star} = \underset{J \in S}{\cap}J$, since $J^{\star}$ consist of one single element from $S$ (is this true? im not sure), we have $J^{\star} \in \Sigma$ and for every $s \in S$ we have $s \leq J^{\star}$ since $J^{\star} \subset s$ (so $J^{\star}$ is our upper bound). Thus $\Sigma$ contain a maximal element by zorns lemma, which according to our partial order is of course a minimal element.

Is this proof valid?

Comment: You should prove that $J^*$ is in your set, not jusy state it.

Comment: Well im thinking that $S$ is a totally ordered set so $J^{\star}$ is just the smallest ideal in $S$, which obviously belongs to $\Sigma$. Isnt this obvious? @JessicaB

Comment: Totally ordered is not the same as well-ordered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is not quite correct: $J^*$ may not be an element of the set $\Sigma$ under consideration (although $J^*$ is a prime ideal, since $S$ is totally ordered).

Indeed, the claim is false: there exist rings with [prime ideals of infinite height](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42510/how-badly-can-krulls-hauptidealsatz-fail-for-non-noetherian-rings). If $p$ is such a prime ideal, then there exist prime ideals $p \supsetneq p_1 \supsetneq p_2 \supsetneq \ldots$, so $\{p, p_1, p_2, \ldots\}$ has no minimal element.

Comment: So you mean that every nonempty set of prime ideals doesnt need to have a minimal element?

Comment: @adam: Yes, see the counterexample in my answer

Comment: This seems very strange, I am asked in my homework to prove this, if it isnt true then....

Comment: @adam: Unfortunately, even homework problems can occasionally have mistakes. It is true that the set of *all* prime ideals has minimal elements. Also, the claim should be true under certain assumptions on the ring (such as being Noetherian)

Comment: So if $\Sigma$ in my case consist of all prime ideal of some commutative ring, the claim is true? Does my proof hold then?

Comment: @adam: Yes, if $\Sigma$ is the set of all primes, then the claim is true, and your proof is fine (you need only check that $J^*$ is a prime ideal)

Comment: I think your statement about $J^{\star}$ is wrong, actually it must be an element of the set $\Sigma$. This is because $J^{\star}$ consist of ONE ideal of $S$ and $S$ is a subset of $\Sigma$, what am I missing here??

Comment: @adam: What is the definition of $J^*$? Why do you think that the intersection of elements of $\Sigma$ (or $S$) is again an element of $\Sigma$ (or $S$)?

Comment: I did not say that the intersection of elements in $\Sigma$ is again an element in $\Sigma$ but I said this is true about $S$, why? Because $S$ is a totally ordered set and the intersection of all elements in $S$ consist of one element of $S$. I dont see why this is wrong.

Comment: Your second sentence is precisely the error: the intersection of elements in a totally ordered set need not be an element of that set

Comment: In my case, with the order I have defined, I believe this is true. I will take a closer look into this.

Comment: @adam: After re-reading this, I realized where the flaw in your logic is. You seem to be assuming that in the totally ordered set $S$, there is one element of $S$ that is largest (which you take as $J^*$). But this is not true - indeed, this is equivalent to saying that $S$ has an upper bound, and is what one needs to *show* in order to apply Zorn's Lemma (thus you were presupposing the conclusion). Finally, note that my counterexample does apply to your specific case (i.e. to the order you have defined)

Comment: After re-reading this aswell, and your counterexample, I realized I was wrong. I have concluded that the statement holds in an integral domain where we can apply the ascending chain condition, is this true? :)

Comment: @adam: Yes, the ascending chain condition is called Noetherianness, and I believe the claim holds in any Noetherian ring (not necessarily a domain). In fact, I believe that for a ring $R$, the claim holds iff every prime ideal of $R$ has finite height